# Why is my window:willPositionSheet:usingRect: delegate method not called?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to reposition a NSAlert window. I found out already, that to do that I need to implement the `(NSRect)window:(NSWindow *)window willPositionSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet usingRect:(NSRect)rect` method in the delegate.

My code where I trigger the Alert Window is in the following method:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    NSAlert* jsAlert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [jsAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [jsAlert setMessageText:@""];
    [jsAlert setInformativeText:message];
    [jsAlert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];
    // [jsAlert setDelegate:self];

    [jsAlert beginSheetModalForWindow:sender.window modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:NULL];
}
```

There I set the `modalDelegate` so `self`, where `self` is the `AppDelegate`. I implemented the following method in the `AppDelegate`:

```
- (NSRect)window:(NSWindow *)window willPositionSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet usingRect:(NSRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"we are here: %s", __func__);
    return NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100); // just fake
}
```

This method won't be called. From what I've found in the documentation this should work though and I cannot comprehend why it doesn't.

I also tried the following, i.e. making the AppDelegate comply to the `NSWindowDelegate`-protocol (and the `NSAlertDelegate` protocol, when commenting in the uncommented line in the first code snippet).

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSAlertDelegate, NSWindowDelegate>
```

I read everywhere that this should just work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Needless to say, that I'm a newbie in Cocoa development ;)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing left to do was to actually register the `AppDelegate` as `NSWindowDelegate` like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // [...]
    [self.window setDelegate:self];
    // [...]
}
```

This sounds very trivial, but then I needed a hell lot of time to find that out, as all examples I saw didn't do it. They just set `modalDelegate` to `self` which in my case should be the `AppDelegate`.

I hope this helps someone out there...

Comment: Yes, it's confusing. The modal delegate is just the object which receives the did-end selector. That's its only role. It's a delegate not of the window nor even of the sheet, but of the sheet presentation operation. It's a completely separate concept from the window's delegate. By the way, `-[NSAlert beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:]` has been deprecated. You should be using `-beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:` instead if you can target 10.9 or later for deployment.

Comment: thx for the comment. I know that the method is deprecated, but I also need to target 10.8, so I thought I'll use the old method. I suppose there's a way to check for the version and use either the old or the new version, but that's for another time :-)